Java _ keyword giving an error with Java 22
As i am aware, the _ for unnamed variables has been a preview feature [java:21] later released with JDK 22.
This is the code in question
        char[] _ = { 'b', 'o', 'b' };

However i get this error
[ERROR]         '_' is a keyword from source level 9 onwards, cannot be used as identifier

Now i had assumed that its a issue with the JDK version Maven is set to build with
so i changed pom.xml
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>22</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>22</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

And that hasn't resolved the issue - so i rather thought of checking it with mavens --show-version:
Maven home: [maven path]
Java version: 22.0.1, vendor: Amazon.com Inc., runtime: [my path]/java/22.0.1-amzn
Default locale: [locale]
OS name: [os info]

for the sake of simplicity i've removed some info
So how do i go about resolving this error?

@SotiriosDelimanolis What im trying to do is to use the _ keyword in Java.  I don't understand your second question - if its a java 22 feature then it will work(without the preview mode) with a java 22 compiler, what seems to be wrong with that? Cause by default its going to use Java 17 which has this keyword but its not entirely the same.

@SotiriosDelimanolis JEP 456 and as i am aware there is virtually no limitation of using this anywhere - rather its not "good practice" per say. However a Youtube video does this same thing however using a non-primitive so i decided to use String and a custom similar class as the Youtuber is using and i still get the error. now i sorted to using the full stack trace with -e but im sure its 100% the _

And yes i have also tried it with lambda and try/catch as the article provided(as a good practice use case but still).

The _ is defined as variable name which is not required to be named because it's ignored... https://openjdk.org/jeps/456 shows possible usages; It is not allowed to be used an identifier alone... Examples: https://github.com/khmarbaise/jdk22/blob/main/src/test/java/com/soebes/jdk22/countdown/Countdown.java

@khmarbaise Perfect. thanks for proving my point. That code base uses some preview features if im right. but thats besides the point im getting a crap ton of [ERROR]         '_' is a keyword from source level 9 onwards, cannot be used as identifier errors

@RyanTheGhost the question misses out on when you get the error. i.e. how shall someone try to reproduce this issue in their machine and get back with findings to resolve.

@Naman I dont see why it doesn't. For one i included the line of code that produces the error. put it in your psvm or any other function and it will produce this same error. I also included the exact version and the vendor of my JDK. and even if that was not enough i literally ran the code provided by khmarbaise which in turn produced the same exact error. So I'm giving 1. 2 ways to reproduce the error 2. My exact JDK version and vendor 3. My build build tool (maven) so what else do you want? the only thing i didnt give is my maven version (3.9.8) so i dont see the problem here.

If you try out your example in jshell does it work there?

@JornVernee It doesn't give an error and returns  ==> char[3] { 'b', 'o', 'b' } so i presume it works. Now how do i get it into my codebase?

Your maven configuration works locally for me. You might want to try running mvn help:effective-pom for the project you're trying to build, to see if the properties are being picked up correctly.

As @JornVernee said, the mentioned configurations are working fine with me too. That's why you've got to clarify the steps to reproduce the issue that you are facing.

@JornVernee Yes they are. One thing i forgot to mention is i can compile the project but can't run it. mvn compile works without an issue but mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=com.ryn.Main --show-version doesn't. any clues? Again i apologize for not including that - that's on me and to @Naman.

@RyanTheGhost the maven goal that you are trying to achieve belongs to a different plugin, so the properties specified don't matter during that goal. This Q&A could be relevant to what you are trying to achieve.

@RyanTheGhost I can further confirm that with the mentioned configuration in the linked Q&A to enable preview for the exec-plugin, I could make it work on my machine. Here is the commit to what I had attempted for.

@Naman thanks alot but i used your exact .mvn/jvm.config file and then ran mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=com.ryn.Main as usual but i still get this error. I know i might sound really dumb but is there something im missing? besides this is a java 22 feature why would i need to use a preview version?

Does there exist an example project?

@khmarbaise could you elaborate? besides it seems like its a weird configuration thing and i have no clue how to fix it

The error is correct. _ cannot be used as an identifier.

@Boann who said so? and if so then how could you catch an exception? besides Naman ran it without an issue. its something on my configuration side that i cant figure out.

You said:

i included the line of code that produces the error. put it in your psvm or any other function and it will produce this same error.

Nope, no such error. Works as documented.
This compiles and runs:
char[] _ = { 'b' , 'o' , 'b' };

Full example:
package work.basil.example.lang;

import java.time.Instant;

public class Underscore
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        System.out.println( Runtime.version( ) );

        int[] _ = { 1 , 2 , 3 };

        String _ = Underscore.getAlice( );

        char[] _ = { 'b' , 'o' , 'b' };
        char[] _ = Underscore.getChars( );

        System.out.println( "End of `main`. " + Instant.now( ) );
    }

    public static String getAlice ( )
    {
        System.out.println( "Getting Alice at " + Instant.now( ) );
        return "Alice";
    }

    public static char[] getChars ( )
    {
        System.out.println( "Getting chars at " + Instant.now( ) );
        return new char[] { 'b' , 'o' , 'b' };
    }
}

When run:
22.0.1+10
Getting Alice at 2024-07-09T19:31:16.269891Z
Getting chars at 2024-07-09T19:31:16.272960Z
End of `main`. 2024-07-09T19:31:16.273040Z

By the way, with modern tooling you can collapse your source & target elements to one release element: <maven.compiler.release>22</maven.compiler.release>.
Here is my complete POM.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>work.basil.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>Ex</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <name>Ex</name>
    <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
    <url>https://www.example.com</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.release>22</maven.compiler.release>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>5.10.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.224</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.mysql/mysql-connector-j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <version>8.4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongodb-driver-sync</artifactId>
            <version>4.11.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains/annotations -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains</groupId>
            <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
            <version>24.1.0</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (can be moved to parent pom) -->
            <plugins>
                <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.3.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.3.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.13.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2.5</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.4.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>4.0.0-M13</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.5.0</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>


By the way, avoid char type. That type has been essentially broken since Java 2, and legacy since Java 5. As a 16-bit value, char is physically incapable of representing most characters. If using char, one emoji could ruin your whole day.

Thanks mate - i ran this without maven and it works perfectly. i assume its some weird maven thing and i'll try to resolve it. Also thanks for your other suggestions

You can see it the other way round; when you know beforehand that you’re only operating with ASCII values, using char[] is wasting memory, as you could use byte[] instead. But for variables named _, you can be sure that their data type won’t cause many problems anyway…
